How to override color selection on DateCalendar Component?
When overriding my color selection, It does not change the color of the transition animation upon being selected. What is the issue?
      <DateCalendar 
      defaultValue={dayjs("2022-04-17")} 
      sx={{
    "&& .Mui-selected, & .Mui-selected:hover": {
      color: "white",
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    },
    boxShadow: 3,
    borderRadius: 5,
      }}
      />

Attempted modifying sx component but doesn't seem to update.

You need to ensure that your CSS selectors target all relevant states of the selected element, including hover and focus states. Use a more specific selector to override the default styles.

Thanks for the comment, I have tried multiple selectors but they don't seem to change the transition. Is there a way to be able to find the selector controlling the transitions CSS?

Right-click the element, inspect, look at the Styles tab, and that way you can identify the selector. Use this selector to override the transition in your code.

DateCalendar from Material UI not applying the color override correctly during transitions is likely related to the specificity of the CSS selectors or the way the Material UI styles are structured.
When you use the sx prop, Material UI generates styles with a certain level of specificity. Try this class:
<DateCalendar
      defaultValue={dayjs("2022-04-17")}
      sx={{
        "&& .Mui-selected, && .Mui-selected:hover, && .Mui-selected.Mui-focusVisible": {
          color: "white",
          backgroundColor: "black",
        },
        boxShadow: 3,
        borderRadius: 5,
      }}
    />

